# SELECTing from other table with LEFT JOIN makes filtering not working

Tags: mysql, left-join, filtering, where-clause

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    r.*, 
    COUNT(rt.id) total_task, 
    IFNULL(SUM(IF(rt.status = 2, 1, 0)), 0) total_task_done
FROM requests AS r
LEFT JOIN request_participants AS rp ON rp.request_id = r.id
LEFT JOIN request_tasks AS rt ON rt.request_id = r.id
WHERE r.id = 10 AND rp.user_id = 3 AND rp.role = 1
```

These are the tables with the data:

- **`requests`**

  ```
  +----+-----------------+--------+
  | id |      notes      | status |
  +----+-----------------+--------+
  | 10 | Some notes here |      1 |
  +----+-----------------+--------+
  ```
- **`request_participants`**

  ```
  +----+---------+------------+------+
  | id | user_id | request_id | role |
  +----+---------+------------+------+
  | 18 |       3 |         10 |    0 |
  | 19 |      17 |         10 |    1 |
  +----+---------+------------+------+
  ```

I want to filter out the `request` data by its `id`, participant's `user_id` and `role`.

When I run the query as exactly the same as the example above, it returns one row (`request.id = 10`), but if I remove the `COUNT(rt.id) total_task, IFNULL(SUM(IF(rt.status = 2, 1, 0)), 0) total_task_done` line from the query, it returns zero row and this is what I wanted.

Could you help me point out what is wrong with my query? Thank you.

Comment: Hi. You don't actually describe how the output is a function of the input. You are hoping we can guess from your example & a wrong query. Say under what circumstances a row appears in your desired result. If necessary or additionally describe output as a function of the result of some query you give returning sufficient data. "filter out the data by [certain fields]" is not clear. Consider asking about a simpler desired output if you know how go correctly go from it to the currrent desired output. Read how group by & aggregates work--aggregates without group by implicitly give one group.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your condition in the `ON` clause so filtering will happen before the actual join and add `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT  r.ID, r.notes, r.status, 
        COUNT(rt.id) total_task, 
        IFNULL(SUM(IF(rt.status = 2, 1, 0)), 0) total_task_done
FROM    requests AS r
        LEFT JOIN request_participants AS rp 
            ON rp.request_id = r.id
                AND rp.user_id = 3
                AND rp.role = 1
        LEFT JOIN request_tasks AS rt 
            ON rt.request_id = r.id
WHERE   r.id = 10 
GROUP   BY r.ID, r.notes, r.status
```

Comment: Are you sure to move the condition to the `ON` clause? Because I tried yours and it's still the same. and by keeping the condition on `WHERE` it works.

Comment: @RizkiPratama because you are using `LEFT JOIN`. If you put condition in the `WHERE` clause for tables request_participants or request_tasks and does not match, it will return nothing. It's like doing `INNER JOIN` instead. Can you show sample out put based from your records above?

Answer (score 0):

Do the filtering on the individual tables then do the joins and aggregation. Try this:

```
SELECT  A.id, A.notes, A.status, 
    SUM(IF(C.id IS NULL, 0, 1)) total_task, 
    IFNULL(SUM(IF(C.status = 2, 1, 0)), 0) total_task_done
FROM (SELECT * FROM requests 
WHERE id = 10) A LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM request_participants WHERE user_id = 3 AND role = 1) B 
 ON A.id=B.request_id LEFT JOIN
 request_tasks C 
 ON A.id=C.request_id
 GROUP BY A.id,  A.notes,  A.status;
```